# How to fix collared shirt clipping issue in cloth simulation

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, error, collision, settings

[image]

I have a collared shirt that I'm running a cloth simulation on that clips through itself whenever I run the simulation. The solution I've been trying so far is making the collar stiff so that it doesn't clip and because collars are supposed to be stiff anyway. To do this I've added a clipping vertex group on the shirt that I've applied to a structural group in the simulation and a surface deform modifier that I found in this tutorial which seems to make things more stiff. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg&t=1118s

[image]
This is how the same collar looks after the 21st frame.

[image]

My face orientation doesn't look like it's the problem either.

Here is the blend file:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try it with this modifier order: *Armature / Cloth / Solidify / Subdivision*:

[image]

Make sure that the vertex groups are correct for the shirt, if it's not the case, parent it again *With Automatic Weights* to the armature or if you want to catch the weights of the body use a *Data Transfer* modifier.

Then create a new *Pin* group in the vertex group list, paint it around the collar, and choose it in the *Cloth panel > Shape > Pin Group*. This way you're sure that the collar will stay stiff:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer man